# react js iterate over array in Component props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got a component where I need to pass data, searched in array. The array is stored in variable, and the data needs to go to Component prop. Consider the following;

```
const users = [
   {"id": 1, "username": 'name1'},
   {"id": 2, "username": 'name2'},
   {"id": 3, "username": 'name3'},
   {"id": 4, "username": 'name4'},
   {"id": 5, "username": 'name5'}
]

const listItemData = [1,2,3];

<List
    size="small"
    bordered
    dataSource={listItemData}
    renderItem={item => <List.Item>{item}</List.Item>}//need name1, name2, name3 but get 1,2,3 here
/>
```

So here I have an array of users where all data about all users is stored, and array of particular list items where I have only ids. For rendering purposes I need to render usernames instead of ids. As far as I know I could iterate through user ids in components `renderItem` prop and show `username` of user that matches its id with id from `listItemData`.

Any ideas how to do that would be welcome. Thank you

Comment: share the code for list component

Comment: its a Component from here: https://ant.design/components/list/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const users = [
  {"id": 1, "username": 'name1'},
  {"id": 2, "username": 'name2'},
  {"id": 3, "username": 'name3'},
  {"id": 4, "username": 'name4'},
  {"id": 5, "username": 'name5'}
];

const ids = [1,2,3];

const listItems = users.reduce((a, c) => {
  a[c.id] = c.username;
  return a;
}, {});

<List
  size="small"
  bordered
  dataSource={ids}
  renderItem={id => <List.Item>{listItems[id]}</List.Item>}
/>
```

Comment: sorry, but your logic is wrong if the array is not in series your logic would fail.
var users = [
  {"id": 10, "username": 'name1'},
  {"id": 9, "username": 'name2'},
  {"id": 0, "username": 'name3'},
  {"id": 4, "username": 'name4'},
  {"id": 5, "username": 'name5'}
];

var ids = [1,2,3];

var listItems = users.reduce((a, c) => {
  a[c.id] = c.username;
  return a;
}, {});//{0: "name3", 4: "name4", 5: "name5", 9: "name2", 10: "name1"} which is wrong and yields wrong result

Comment: if the input is wrong, I don't think it's a huge problem displaying a blank item. wrong input, wrong result. it's okay as long as it doesn't break.

Comment: It is a test case and it should be considered. Your whole assumption is based on the input serial which is not asked in the question

Comment: it can be considered by the OP easily. for example, he can add `|| N/A` in the renderItem method. that's not the point of the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { List, Avatar } from 'antd';

const users = [
  {"id": 1, "username": 'name1'},
  {"id": 2, "username": 'name2'},
  {"id": 3, "username": 'name3'},
  {"id": 4, "username": 'name4'},
  {"id": 5, "username": 'name5'}
]

const listItemData = [1,2,3];


const data = users.filter((user)=>listItemData.includes(user.id))
ReactDOM.render(
  <List
    itemLayout="horizontal"
    dataSource={data}
    renderItem={item => (
      <List.Item>
        <List.Item.Meta          
          title={<a href="https://ant.design">{item.username}</a>}          
        />
      </List.Item>
    )}
  />,
  document.getElementById('container'),
);
```

You need to filter out the values and then set that as new data source. By the way in your code you took wrong datasource. First filter out matching data and then it works like a charm!!!

Comment: is it possible to do the same withut changing the data source. I am getting the data source from the state, and unfortunately I cannot change it to array of objects, I get only array of integers. Thank you

Comment: the component iterates over data source if that is not correct then how will you get correct data. your array would always contain [1,2,3]. You need to make source correct.

Comment: you can simply copy and paste this code in https://codesandbox.io/s/3052nky8q and check what I am trying to tell you.

Comment: FWIW, `includes` doesn't work with IE. better to use `indexOf`

Comment: FYI react js code has inbuilt babel to execute this regardless of browser